# Is it possible to load a model which is stored with model.module.state_dict() but load with model.state_dict()

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I want to ask a question, I have trained a model with two gpus and stored this model with
model.module.state_dict(), now I want to load this model in one gpu, can I directly load this trained model with model.state_dict()?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-keyerror-unexpected-key-module-encoder-embedding-weight-in-state-dict/1686) question.

You can either adding an `nn.DataParallel` for loading purpose. Or change the key naming like

```
# original saved file with DataParallel
state_dict = torch.load('myfile.pth.tar')
# create new OrderedDict that does not contain `module.`
from collections import OrderedDict
new_state_dict = OrderedDict()
for k, v in state_dict.items():
    name = k[7:] # remove `module.`
    new_state_dict[name] = v
# load params
model.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)
```

But as you save the model with `model.module.state_dict()` instead of `model.state_dict()` it possible that the names may differed. If the two methods above don't work try print the saved dict and model to see what you need to change. Like

```
state_dict = torch.load('myfile.pth.tar')
print(state_dict)
print(model)
```